# Form sending value rather than name in html

Tags: html, django-forms, forms, http-post

This is my html code:

```
<form id="commentform" action="." method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}
                    <label for="comment">Comment</label>
                    <textarea></textarea>
                 <div class="clearfix"></div>
                   <input type="submit" id="submit" name="body" value="send">
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
               </form>
```

I'm using this form to send data but instead of sending any input from user it always sends "Send" to server. How to cope with it, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a `name=""` as a `textarea` attribute.

Try using:

```
<form id="commentform" action="." method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
                <label for="comment">Comment</label>
                <textarea name="textarea"></textarea>
             <div class="clearfix"></div>
               <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Send">
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
           </form>
```